# How to enforce chromium on Android to send credentials?

Tags: android, chromium, credentials, m3u8

I set up a nginx server for live play of videos. It works well without user authentication. With authentication it still works on any platform (windows, mac, ios) but Android. In the log files (given below) I found out that after reading the `index.m3u8` file successfully, the browser on Android tries to read it again but second time without user credentials thus giving rise to a 401 error and an error message in the video player.

I already tried different settings for `crossorigin` and different js-scripts without success. I figured out that the behaviour I observe in the log files of nginx right after the successful read of `index.m3u8` is exactly what happens when directly using the URL of the `index.m3u8` file within the Android browser instead of making it the source within a video tag. It thus occurs to me that Android tries to avoid using the js-player and uses its native player instead but now without sending credentials. Furthermore, the log files do not show the full URL of my server for that last GET which they do for all the successful reads with credentials (`"-"` instead of `"https://xxxx/"` reported in log file).

Here is the code of nginx's index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>live stream</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/5.8/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/video.js/6.5.1/video.min.js></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-contrib-hls/5.12.2/videojs-contrib-hls.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>live stream</h1>
        <video id="stream"
            class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
            width="840"
            height="525"
            style="max-width: 100%"
            controls
            crossorigin="use-credentials"
            preload="none"
            data-setup='{}'>
            <source src="https://xxxx/live/Stream/index.m3u8" 
type="application/x-mpegURL">
        </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here are the related lines of the log file (same using different android phones):

`1xx.7x.1xx.210 - user [06/May/2019:16:00:05 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 535 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; ANE-LX1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.90 Mobile Safari/537.36"`

`1xx.7x.1xx.210 - user [06/May/2019:16:00:10 +0200] "GET /live/Stream/index.m3u8 HTTP/1.1" 200 145 "https://xxxx/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; ANE-LX1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.90 Mobile Safari/537.36"`

`1xx.7x.1xx.210 - user [06/May/2019:16:00:10 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 199 "https://xxxx/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; ANE LX1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.90 Mobile Safari/537.36"`

`1xx.7x.1xx.210 - - [06/May/2019:16:00:10 +0200] "GET /live/Stream/index.m3u8 HTTP/1.1" 401 597 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; ANE-LX1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.90 Mobile Safari/537.36"`

For the other devices, there is no second read to `index.m3u8` but the ts files are loaded and played.